# Select Parent XML(Entire Hierarchy) Elements based on Child element values LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following XML and query through the ID,how do get the Parent Hierarchy

```
<Child>
    <Child1 Id="1">
        <Child2 Id="2">
            <Child3 Id="3">
                <Child4 Id="4">
                    <Child5 Id="5"/>
                    <Child6 Id="6"/>
                </Child4>
            </Child3>
        </Child2>
    </Child1>
</Child>
```

In this if i query(Id = 4) and find out the Parent elements using Linq in the particular element how to get the following output with Hierarchy.

```
<Child>
    <Child1 Id="1">
        <Child2 Id="2">
            <Child3 Id="3">
                <Child4 Id="4"/>
            </Child3>
        </Child2>
    </Child1>
</Child>
```

Thanks In Advance.

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: I am trying but no success till now.

Comment: this issue seems to be more suited for a recursive algorithm than for linq.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you want just one node parent tree:

```
string xml = @"<Child>
                <Child1 Id="1">
                  <Child2 Id="2">
                    <Child3 Id="3">
                      <Child4 Id="4">
                        <Child5 Id="5"/>
                        <Child6 Id="6"/>
                      </Child4>
                  </Child3>
                 </Child2>
               </Child1>
             </Child>";

TextReader tr = new StringReader(xml);
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(tr);

IEnumerable<XElement> myList =
    from el in doc.Descendants()
    where (string)el.Attribute("Id") == "4" // here whatever you want
    select el; 

// select your hero element in some way

XElement hero = myList.FirstOrDefault();

foreach (XElement ancestor in hero.Ancestors())
{
    Console.WriteLine(ancestor.Name); // rebuild your tree in a separate document, I print ;)
}
```

To search for every element of your tree iterate retrieve the node with the select query without the where clause and call the foreach for every element.

Answer (score 0):

In Linq to XML there is a method called [`AncestorsAndSelf`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb346865.aspx) on [`XElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340098.aspx) that

> Returns a collection of elements that contain this element, and the
>   ancestors of this element.

But it will not transform your XML tree the way you want it.

What you want is:

- For a given element, find the parent
- Remove all elements from parent but the given element
- Remove all elements from the given element

Something like this in Linq (no error handling):

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse("<xml content>");

//finding element having 4 as ID for example
XElement el = doc.Descendants().First(el => el.Attribute("Id").Value == "4");

el.RemoveNodes();
XElement parent = el.Parent;
parent.RemoveNodes();
parent.Add(el);
```

**[Edit]**
`doc.ToString()` must give you what you want as a string.

**[Edit]**

- Using `RemoveNodes` instead of `RemoveAll`, the last one also removes attributes.
- Removing nodes from the chosen element too.

Comment: For your case i don't know in the which level it contains the id in my real example. Anyhow thanks for the response

Comment: In my example that part is not important, it is only to illustrate how to get a given element. I will edit the answer to point that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the sample XML provided, you could walk up the tree to find the parent node once you've found the node in question:

```
string xml =
@"<Child>
  <Child1 Id='1'>
    <Child2 Id='2'>
      <Child3 Id='3'>
        <Child4 Id='4'>
          <Child5 Id='5'/>
            <Child6 Id='6'/>
        </Child4>
     </Child3>
   </Child2>
  </Child1>
</Child>";


var doc = XDocument.Parse( xml );

// assumes there will always be an Id attribute for each node
// and there will be an Id with a value of 4
// otherwise an exception will be thrown.
XElement el = doc.Root.Descendants().First( x => x.Attribute( "Id" ).Value == "4" );
// discared all child nodes
el.RemoveNodes();

// walk up the tree to find the parent; when the
// parent is null, then the current node is the 
// top most parent.
while( true )
{
    if( el.Parent == null )
    {
        break;
    }

    el = el.Parent;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I found the following way

```
XElement elementNode = element.Descendants()
                                .FirstOrDefault(id => id.Attribute("id").Value == "4");
        elementNode.RemoveNodes();
        while (elementNode.Parent != null)
        {
            XElement lastNode = new XElement(elementNode);
            elementNode = elementNode.Parent;
            elementNode.RemoveNodes();
            elementNode.DescendantsAndSelf().Last().AddFirst(lastNode);
        }
```

return or Print elementNode.